# mobile tap event issue

Tags: javascript, mobile, tap

I am facing issue with tap event on mobile devices.

create 3 divs with same height. Tap on second div to hide the first div and it will trigger the event on third div.

sample code: reproducible in chrome device simulator

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>phone issue</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    .hide {
    display: none;
}
#one, #two, #three {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#two').on('tap', function () {
            $('#one').toggle();
        });

        $('#three').on('tap', function () {
            alert('you just clicked me!');
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
<div id="one">hide</div>
<div id="two">main</div>
<div id="three">click</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use 'click' event instead of 'tap' event. I run in to the same issue and manage to solve it by using 'click' event. Please see jquery mobile documentation for details: https://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/. Regards.